# bbpress forum functionality

Tags: html, bbpress

I recently began using bbpress on my website, but have been so far unsuccessful in implementing or finding an answer for some of the things I need my forum to do. If possible, what would be the easiest ways of implementing the following:
Limiting the length of replies on the forum by a minimum and maximum word/character amount.
Limiting a user on the forum to only have X replies per thread.
Limiting the length of a thread to X amount of replies.
Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to use the support and documentation of bbpress itself

Comment: I have read the documentation, searched the forums, looked up tutorials and still no luck. I'd poke around the code too but with my limited coding knowledge i'm afraid i'll do more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the length of replies on the forum by a minimum and maximum word/character amount: You would have to either edit the template file which renders those inputs, or create a template override with the edits.

Not sure what you mean by limit user to x replies.

Limiting a thread to X replies would require customization of the template files which render the replies, either by editing the original or creating a template override and modifying the sql query to X results.